# Display table across multiple columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to format an SSRS report. At the top there is a dynamic image the runs across the top. Below that is a two column table. The table is long and runs onto the next page. Instead of going to the next page I want the table to continue on the same page into another column.

Answer (score 2):

Add a column to your input data that contains either a 0 or 1. Add a row group to your tablix that uses this column to place the data in two columns. Alternately you can calculate the 0 or 1 by taking the modulo of the curent row count and 2.

Answer (score 1):

The following article explains a method how to split the data over multiple columns in the same table: [Creating Multiple-Column Reports](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/)

It more or less uses the approach as suggested by @Dewey but contains more details so should be easier to get it implemented.  And there's a sample RDL that can be downloaded in case you're struggling with a particular step.

Answer (score 0):

To setup multiple columns select Report from the combo-box at the top of the Properties pane and then in the Columns field type the number of columns you'd like in the report. I believe this only works in print-preview however.

Comment: This does not give me the desired result. Actually, all it seems to do is lay white spaces over my content. Maybe I need to set the columns before adding content?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can only set up columns on the entire report. This means that you would need to format your report layout to fit on half a page, for example, if you needed 2 columns. I haven't found an option to have the ONLY the table continue on a new "column"

Comment: What you're referring to, newsletter-style reports (created by setting the Columns property), only has an effect on exports to PDF and IMAGE. In most cases it isn't very useful, such as in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sqlreportingservices/thread/8b1c7049-64b2-4093-86cb-788944c03dca

I managed to have 6 columns in my report by using a List with embeded table and in the list I set Group on =Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/26)